# How to add data locally and add value by its id?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
         <head>
          <title>HTML5 localStorage (name/value item pairs) demo</title>
          <style >
            td, th {
              font-family: monospace;
              padding: 4px;
              background-color: #ccc;
            }
            #hoge {
              border: 1px dotted blue;
              padding: 6px;
              background-color: #ccc;
              margin-right: 50%;
            }
            #items_table {
              border: 1px dotted blue;
              padding: 6px;
              margin-top: 12px;
              margin-right: 50%;
            }
            #items_table h2 {
              font-size: 18px;
              margin-top: 0px;
              font-family: sans-serif;
            }
            label {
              vertical-align: top;
            }
          </style>
         </head>
         <body onload="doShowAll()">
          <h1>HTML5 localStorage (name/value item pairs) demo</h1>

          <form name=editor>

            <div id="hoge">
             <p>
             <label>Value: <textarea name=data cols=41 rows=10></textarea></label>
             </p>

             <p>
              <label>Name: <input name=name></label>
              <input type=button value="getItem()" onclick="doGetItem()">
              <input type=button value="setItem()" onclick="doSetItem()">
              <input type=button value="removeItem()" onclick="doRemoveItem()">
             </p>
           </div>

           <div id="items_table">
             <h2>Items</h2>
             <table id=pairs></table>
             <p>
             <label><input type=button value="clear()" onclick="doClear()"> <i>* clear() removes all items</i></label>
             </p>
           </div>


           <script>



function doSetItem() {
    var name = document.forms.editor.name.value;
    var data = document.forms.editor.data.value;
    var origData = localStorage.getItem(name) || 0;
    localStorage.setItem(name, parseInt(origData) + parseInt(data));
    doShowAll();
}



             function doGetItem() {
               var name = document.forms.editor.name.value;
               document.forms.editor.data.value = localStorage.getItem(name);
               doShowAll();
             }

             function doRemoveItem() {
               var name = document.forms.editor.name.value;
               document.forms.editor.data.value = localStorage.removeItem(name);
               doShowAll();
             }

             function doClear() {
               localStorage.clear();
               doShowAll();
             }

             function doShowAll() {
               var key = "";
               var pairs = "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>\n";
               var i=0;
               for (i=0; i<=localStorage.length-1; i++) {
                 key = localStorage.key(i);
                 pairs += "<tr><td>"+key+"</td>\n<td>"+localStorage.getItem(key)+"</td></tr>\n";
               }
               if (pairs == "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>\n") {
                 pairs += "<tr><td><i>empty</i></td>\n<td><i>empty</i></td></tr>\n";
               }
               document.getElementById('pairs').innerHTML = pairs;
             }

           </script>

          </form>

         </body>
        </html>
```

Hi friends,
            I wants to locally save the data,now I am able to save the data locally by the code.even if I give the same name the value is getting added and saved locally.but the name should be shown in order of high value to low(example: Ram 20,Renu 18,green 2 like wise...).so how to do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you reword your specific problem?

Comment: Hi Drazen Bjelovuk, Actually i want to store name and value locally.If suppose i am entering your name and Value 2.it should store your name and value and if suppose i am adding your name once again and adding value 3, It should add value(2+3=5) and show it to your name.. got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function doSetItem() {
    var name = document.forms.editor.name.value;
    var data = document.forms.editor.data.value;
    var origData = localStorage.getItem(name) || 0;
    localStorage.setItem(name, parseInt(origData) + parseInt(data));
    doShowAll();
}
```

To display them in descending order:

```
function doShowAll() {
    var key = "";
    var pairs = "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>\n";
    var userArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= localStorage.length - 1; i++) {
        key = localStorage.key(i);
        userArray.push({name:key, value:parseInt(localStorage.getItem(key))});
    }
    userArray.sort(function(a, b){
        return b.value - a.value;
    });
    userArray.forEach(function(user){
        pairs += "<tr><td>" + user.name + "</td>\n<td>" + user.value + "</td></tr>\n";
    });
    if (pairs === "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>\n") {
        pairs += "<tr><td><i>empty</i></td>\n<td><i>empty</i></td></tr>\n";
    }
    document.getElementById('pairs').innerHTML = pairs;
}
```

Comment: Thank You Drazen. Is it possible to get the data as per highest vale.. for example Drazen 20,Ram 18. if suupose you add highest value than 20 it should come first..but actualy now i am getting by alphabetical order or numerical order.so  kindly help me

Comment: Now i am unable to aask question,still i have 5 days.so pls help me out

Comment: @ Drazen Bjelovuk, No its not displaying value descending order

Comment: Should be. How is it displaying it?

Comment: @ Drazen Bjelovuk ,its showing randomly not in proper format

Comment: Yes Thank you @Drazen Bjelovuk. Its working now,but Why its not working after 4 digit value?

Comment: Sorry, wrap your `getItem` call in a `praseInt`. See update.

Answer (score 0):

For what I can see in your code, you're just replacing the value, you need to get the existent value from the localStorage first, append to it the new one and then asign the result to the localStorage.

Comment: Actually i want to store name and value locally.If suppose i am entering your name and Value 2.it should store your name and value and if suppose i am adding your name once again and adding value 3, It should add value(2+3=5) and show it to your name.. got it?